# Perl comments on a Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, perl

I am trying to run a Perl script I wrote from the command line. The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#open file
open(READFILE,"<prune.txt") || die "Couldn't open file";
#read line
while (<READFILE>)
{
#seperate line into pieces
$txtline = $_;
$txtline =~ m/(\d+)\t([\w\s]+)/i;
#rename file
print("Rename $2 to $1.\n");
#loop
}
close (READFILE);
```

and when I run it in Terminal I get the error: `#open: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/perl`); perhaps wrong _end of line_ terminator?! Please check if your program runs when you invoke it with `perl scriptname.pl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vi to convert the Perl script, say `perl_script.pl`, to UNIX file format (`:set ff=unix`) as follows:

```
vi perl_script.pl
```

Now in `vi`, change the file format to UNIX, save the file, and then quit, as in:

```
:set ff=unix
:wq
```

Now run your script as before.

The problem is most likely that the file was created or got converted to some other format other than UNIX format, perhaps DOS (`:set ff=dos` in `vi`).

It would appear that at least in my Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LRS installation, the age old tools, `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` are not installed by default.  This would have been what I'd have suggested if they were readily available - hence the above hack to get you going.  Since they aren't currently available, here is a pretty straight forward way to get them back:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tofrodos
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/fromdos /usr/bin/dos2unix
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/todos /usr/bin/unix2dos
```

Now, to see how to use `dos2unix`, perform a `man fromdos`, and to see how to use `unix2dos`, perform a `man todos`.

Add the following to one of your shell startup files to code up your own `dos2unx` and `unix2dos` i.e. your `.bashrc` file:

```
dos2unix(){
  tr -d '\r' < "$1" > t
  mv -f t "$1"
}
dos2unix file

unix2dos(){
  sed -i 's/$/\r/' "$1"
}
unix2dos file
```

Because it was easier to do the latter coding, this is what I did for my OSX server, rather than figure out which package to find and port to OSX.

Comment: Yep it does have to do with unix.  I use TextWrangle and all had to do is set encodings to unix in the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean to have the "<" character in the file name ?
Almost all bugs like this are to do with trying to access a file with a typo in the name.

Comment: No, this is how perl opens a file for read